# Possibility to Install a managed package on production while package is under Security Review

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, push-upgrade

We are working on a managed package, which we are planning to submit for security review in a few weeks.

While the package will be in the security review, we would also like to install the managed package for one of the pilot customers. We understand that if we install the uncertified package on a pilot customer's org, they will not get advantages of the governor limits which are available with certified packages. Also, the package may not work on the professional and essentials edition until the package will be certified.

**Question:** If we install the managed package (which is submitted in security review and not passed yet) to the customer's production org, can we update the licenses once the app will pass the security review? Or, we need to create a new version and then customers can upgrade the package to get the advantages of certified packages.

Are there are any known issues in this situation, due to which we should wait till the app passes the SR?

Thanks in advance.